# Image resize in php?

Tags: php, css, image, resize

How can i resize proportionaly image in php without "squishing" ? I need some solution, i was searching here, but i could't find anything what i need. 
**What i have:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif');
        $max_filesize      = 10485760;
        $upload_path       = 'gallery/';
        $filename          = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $ext               = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.'), strlen($filename) - 1);

        if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_filetypes)) {
            die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
        }

        if (filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) {
            die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
        }

        if (!is_writable($upload_path)) {
            die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$filename)) {
            $q = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET avatar='".$_FILES['userfile']['name']."' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
            echo "<font color='#5cb85c'>Браво, успешно си качил/а профилна снимка!</font>";
        } else {
            echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
        }
    }
    echo ' <form action="images.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ';
    echo ' <input type="file" name="userfile"/>';
    echo ' <input type="submit" name="upload"  value="Качи">';
    echo ' </form>';
} else {
    echo "<font color='#ec3f8c'>Съжелявам! За да  качиш снимка във профила си, <a href='login.php'><font color='#ec3f8c'><b> трябва да се логнеш</b> </font></a></font>";
}
?>
```

I want to add something like this:[Click here](http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/01/php-how-to-proportionally-resize-an-uploaded-image/)

how i call images?

```
echo '<a href="profiles.php?id='.$rowtwo['id'].'">';
  echo"<img src='gallery/".$rowtwo['avatar']."' width='170px' height='217px'/>"; 
  echo'</a>';
```

I save my image of avatar in DB in users as avatar.

Comment: Where in your code do you resize the image?

Comment: Not yet, i dont know how to do that. can you help me with that to edit code ?

Comment: @user3748181 http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362

Comment: your link says all, why dont you just follow that

Comment: Yes, i know, but how can i connect my code with the code which i posted i mean the link which i posted?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use JS. It also works better because you're letting the client do the slow work of manipulation vs using your finite server resources for that task.

Here's a sample:

```
//This is the URL to your original image
var linkUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png";
//This is a div that is necessary to trick JS into letting you manipulate sizing
//Just make sure it exists and is hidden
var img = $('#HiddenDivForImg');

//This is a call to the function
image_GetResizedImage(img, linkUrl);

//This function does the magic
function image_GetResizedImage(img, linkUrl) {
    //Set your max height or width dimension (either, not both)
    var maxDim = 330;
    //Define the equalizer to 1 to avoid errors if incorrect URL is given
    var dimEq = 1;

    //This determines if the larger dimension is the images height or width.
    //Then, it divides that dimension by the maxDim to get a decimal number for size reduction
    if (img.height() > maxDim || img.width() > maxDim) {
        if (img.height() > img.width()) {
            dimEq = maxDim / img.height();
        } else {
            dimEq = maxDim / img.width();
        }
    }

    var imageOutput = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>View Larger</a><br /><a href='" + result +
        "' target='_blank'><img src='" + linkUrl + "' style='width: " + img.width() * dimEq
        + "px; height: " + img.height() * dimEq + "px' /></a>";

    //This returns a URL for the image with height and width tags of the resized (non-squished) image.
    return imageOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For image manipulation in PHP you can use Imagemagick.
http://www.imagemagick.org/

It's the scale command you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a function with your reference link, you can use it like this

**Call it**

```
//Resize uploaded image 
resize_image($_FILES['userfile'], 100, 200);

//Or if you want to save image with diffrent name
$filename = $upload_path.$_SESSION['username'].'-avatar.jpg';
resize_image($_FILES['userfile'], 100, 200, $newfilename);

//if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$filename)) {
        $q = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET avatar='".$filename."' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");


        echo "<font color='#5cb85c'>Браво, успешно си качил/а профилна снимка!</font>";
    } else {
        echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
    }
```

**Function**

```
function resize_image($image_src, $w = 100, $h = 100, $save_as = null) {
    // Create image from file
    switch(strtolower($image_src['type']))
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_src['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_src['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_src['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: '.$image_src['type']);
    }

    // Target dimensions
    $max_width = $w;
    $max_height = $h;

    // Get current dimensions
    $old_width  = imagesx($image);
    $old_height = imagesy($image);

    // Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
    $scale      = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

    // Get the new dimensions
    $new_width  = ceil($scale*$old_width);
    $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);

    // Create new empty image
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    // Resize old image into new
    imagecopyresampled($new, $image,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

    if($save_as) {
        //Save as new file 
        imagejpeg($new, $save_as, 90);
    }else{
        //Overwrite image 
        imagejpeg($new, $image_src['tmp_name'], 90);
    }
       // Destroy resources
           imagedestroy($image);
       imagedestroy($new);
}
```

Comment: where i shoud put functions code ? and how to call it later on ? Sorry i am beginner.

Comment: put function above first line right before `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

I use http://image.intervention.io/. You can scale, cache, store, convert and do various image manipulation tasks.

Very easy to use.

```
// load the image
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// resize the width of the image to 300 pixels and constrain proportions.
$img->resize(300, null, true);

// save file as png with 60% quality
$img->save('public/bar.png', 60);
```